# Radio Electronics

Tags: radio

I'm a beginner in radio electronics. I have basic experience building circuits with both passive and active components.

I was wondering if it was at all possible to build your own transmitter, receiver, etc. (basic radio components) as a good beginner project. For now, I'll start with AM radio.

I've searched the Internet for tutorials, but the links have either made it seem too complicated or they aren't actually simple.

Anyways, if you all could refer me to some beginner material, that would be great.

By the way, if my question is too vague, let me know and I can edit it. I'm new to the whole Stack Exchange too.

Comment: Any type of radio in particular? AM radio transmitters and receivers are not to difficult to make, but make sure you check local regulations if you are going to make a transmitter.

Comment: Can you share some of the links with projects that were "too complicated". Then we can at least tell you whether there's a simpler option avaialable.

Comment: Perhaps look on Amateur Radio SE

Comment: @Tom what do you mean by type?

Comment: @Chu I already did that. Someone replied that Amateur Radio doesn't really delve into the electronics side.

Comment: Tom meant SSB, CW or FM. Amateur radio does involve electronics, you have to know quite a lot about it to get a license.

Comment: In terms of type, I was asking about application (but the comment about Amateur Radio SE answers that) and whether you were thinking one of the AM methods or FM.

Comment: @Tom I guess I'll start with AM

Comment: There's not too much of interest on AM these days, apart from HF broadcast stations. SSB has most of the voice amateur traffic, but data modes are very popular. If you want to listen to ham bands, you can do it on the internet via 'software defined radio' - one of the best is in the Netherlands, give it a try: http://websdr.ewi.utwente.nl:8901/

Comment: ... I would suggest a HF receiver kit if you want to build - you can begin to design/build your own when you gain a bit of experience. Remember, you need a licence to transmit - qualifying for a novice licence needs some effort, but it's worth it.

Comment: Start with a crystal radio. Beginner of beginner project

Comment: You can use this simple design for a receiver and it only uses one transistor, i built and i could listen to the local AM station.  link: http://www.homemade-circuits.com/2012/05/make-this-one-transistor-radio-receiver.html